Is it possible to not have that initial big burst of smoke when doing smoke sim

Im trying to do an airflow simulation with the smoke sim, but it always has that initial big burst of smoke rather than a smooth start
Im quiet new to using the simulations in blender so any addition tips on this would be great.
Im currently having to use the initial velocity as the force since the wind and vortex forcefield make the smoke super choppy and unrealistic

Pretty sure you need to set the Frame Start to a negative number so that your simulation starts and is able to "ramp up" before the actual scene frames do.

You can do one of the following things: either as @Jakemoyo said, set the Cache > Frame Start value in the smoke domain to a negative value. How much is dependent on your scene, the resolution, the flow settings, probably Dissolve settings etc. or the other ethod would be, start simulation at frame 1, but after you have baked the cache, use a negative Offset value to skip the first part of the siulation. In both cases you will to simulate more than you will be able to use afterwards of course since it will be cropped.

For the choppy and unrealistic smoke when using force fields: hard to tell, this can depend on the domain settings, the flow object's settings (how many Sampling Substeps have you set for example), the force field settings...
